# How to make first user became admin in Devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to make first user became admin.

So I have string attribute admin and I need to make some before filter or override Devise registration controller. Something like:

```
if User.first?
  User.admin = "admin"
  User.save
end
```

Here is devise regitration action

```
 def new
  resource = build_resource({})
  respond_with resource
end
```

What would be the better way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your code is not running very often (only when running your app in production for the first time) I would simply write a Rake task that does this for you once instead of cluttering your application code.

Put this in your `Rakefile`

```
task :promote_admin => :environment do
  User.first.update_attribute('admin', 'admin')
end
```

This way you keep your code clean while still having a very easy way to promote the first user during installation.

If you want to promote the first user you simply run `rake promote_admin` from the console and the first User will be promoted to admin.

Comment: @Tigraine thanks amigo - but it begs the question: how would one create the first user in production?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Instead of promoting the first existing user you could just create it inside your rake task (`User.new(...).save`)

Answer (score 2):

A better way would be to have `admin` field as `boolean`. And add the following `before_filter` to your model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_admin

  private
  def set_admin
    self.admin = User.count == 0
  end
end
```

For this to work perfectly, you can have the following in your migration file

```
create_table(:users) do |t|
  t.boolean :admin, null: false, default: false
  ...
end
```

This will make the first user admin. Also, when you delete all your users and then a new user registers, this new user will be admin.

Comment: thanks but it didnt quite work for me i had to change it a bit like i put on the answer below

Answer (score 2):

it didn't work for me i had to change it a bit like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  after_create :set_admin

  private
  def set_admin
   if  User.count == 1
     User.first.update_attribute(:admin, true)
   else
     return true
   end
  end
end
```