# Rails 4: making the first user an admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using FB and G+ for authentication. How do I make the first user that is registered an admin? I've looked at a few answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11557919/2744900) one, but I get errors (like "undefined method `update_attribute' for nil:NilClass" for the previous linked answer) and they are mostly old and for devise gem.

users_controller

```
  def update 
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update(user_params)
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
  end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:admin, :banned)
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the update action on a user is anything to do with making a user an admin. What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be done in the `db/seeds.rb` file which you can execute with `rake db:seed`. The linking with Facebook and G+ will have to be done after the fact. I would not depend on any solution that automatically promotes the first user to admin status. That should only ever done explicitly.

Example `seeds.rb`:

```
# This example is using Devise, however it can easily be adapted to whatever
# setup you require as there is nothing "devise" specific here.
user = User.find_or_create_by(email: "Admin Email")
user.password = "Admin Password"
user.admin = true
user.save
```

Another tool I use is by registering a user normally and then manually promoting them to Admin status via a tool like `rails console`.

**EDIT**

If you still wish to pursue your method (which I consider unsafe) then you can use `ActiveRecord` hooks like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # relations and stuff
  before_save :check_to_make_admin

  private

  def check_to_make_admin
    # Only the first user should be made admin
    if User.count == 0
      self.admin = true
    end
  end
end
```

It's important to note that **I strongly discourage this approach and recommned using the seed method which was created for purposes like this.**